# Is there such a thing as a backless junction box/conduit fitting?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, cabling, cable-management

I have a battery enclosure for a small off-grid solar installation, and I want to run the battery cables out of the enclosure to the DC breakers and inverter. I'm looking for a backless junction box of some sort to mount on the back of the battery enclosure to attach the cabling conduit to. I can cut out a 6'' x 6'' area on the back of the enclosure to mount the junction box to, run the cables from the inside of the enclosure into the junction box, and then (preferably) through punch-outs of conduit fittings at the top. Does anyone know of such a product?

Comment: There are junction boxes with holes in the back and in the sides.  Are holes in the back good enough?

Comment: ideally what I'm looking for is a junction box that can be surface mounted, but the face that is surface mounted is either backless or has conduit cutouts. Removable cover on the opposite face, and two outlets on one side for the cable run to the breaker box and inverter. Does that make sense?

Comment: Google "11b extension" and/or "1900 extension" either should work for what you describe.

Comment: Interesting, those are extensions for other junction boxes, but it should work. Thank you!

Comment: @Tyson, you should make that an answer with a picture.  Sounds _perfect_ for the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an 11b extension ring or a 1900 extension ring.  Actually made to deepen a junction box, but should work for this application.

[image: 1900 extension ring]